# Storing strings in a Database that are only visible to their owner who stored them when they were logged in

Tags: node.js, postgresql, security, encryption, jwt

In my application, logged-in users create some strings, and those strings are stored in the Postgres database.

But, because they are in plaintext, their values are visible to me, as I have access to the database.

Is there a way to do some encryption on a string, that won't be available to see the actual value in the database, but the only user who created it, should be able to seamlessly decrypt, and be able to use that actual string when they are logged in?

I know that for passwords we normally use hashing, but it can only be used to verify if the actual string matches the hashed string. However, in my case, the owner should be able to get the **actual value** that he/she originally stored (while making it impossible for me to get it from the database).

P.S: For authentication, I use JWT tokens, and user passwords are hashed using [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs).

Comment: You could encrypt the strings with a key belonging only to the user that created the string, in this way only him/her can read the actual value by decrypting it using the key and retrieving the string value. To do so you can use nodejs crypto https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Comment: maybe RLS would be suitable for your case: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: You can implement it as a common solution.  Just add a system table to store the "saltInfo" for each logged in user.  The saltInfo is auto-generated by your application.
When they logged in,  load the saltinfo and apply your crypto related service to decrypt it. The other user only can see the encrypted content stored in your original table.